How could "the mind" be uncomputable if it's due to neurons processing information?
This is going to be a very naïve question:
Some biologists, physicists and computer scientists say that what our brain does (generally speaking "the mind", including our thoughts, our reasoning, our feelings, our consciousness...) may not be computable
But our brain is just a bunch of neurons processing information. Couldn't that "hardware" or that way of processing information be reproduced by a computer? Isn't it trivial?

Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54581/5038, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54581/5038.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Our mission is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future.  There is little point in us repeating material that is already well documented.  To this end, we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking.  Also, this helps you formulate a specific question and share background and context to make it relevant for others.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.  In this case, searching for keywords like "mind computable" and "brain computable" seems to immediately turn up lots of discussion and resources.

If you'd like the question to be answered, I encourage you to revise it based on the feedback here and on TCS.SE (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54581/5038).

The basic issue is not that the brain doesn't process information in the general sense.
The issue is that the brain does not "compute" the information in any familiar sense (like the procedures of a bureaucracy or like the workings of a mechanical digital computer).
There's a tendency to become over-general about these things. A centrifugal governor controls a steam engine, but is it a "computer" or does it "compute information"? I would say not, by any conventional definition.
There's typically a line where either the brain isn't a computer as we know it, or it is a computer but so is the entire physical world and everything else in it, rendering the word "computation" meaningless and just a synonym for "things happening".
The body and human society most closely corresponds to an analog control system, the complications of which are beyond our full comprehension, and are certainly beyond any practical form of technological emulation.
The individual brain does not work in isolation from the body or from the collective (which reproduces bodies and brains, and is capable of communication, specialisation of roles, etc.).
It is at least arguable that it is beyond emulation in theory too, since the setup would essentially have to correspond to the real world in every respect, and because the human species is specifically adapted for working within the real world.
The ability to put man-made machines on the workbench and test them, is a function we specifically design into them in order to supervise and control them (and doing so in an effective way is part of the art of good machine design).
And the ability to execute or evaluate the workings of man-made machines by alternative means than their normal operation in use, often in a way that keeps their progression under control, is something that relies on our ability to grasp in our minds how they are working in the first place, and there are often features (or limitations) of man-made designs whose purpose is to facilitate this human analysis.
Biology is not a product of human design in the first place, so biology has not been limited by any limitations that humans have on their own machine design capacity, nor by our desire to remain in control of the design.
